# How to extend my navbar menu when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So if you visit [**ryanteaches.com**](http://ryanteaches.com), and hover over `GCSEs`, you will see the dropdown of `Chemistry`, `Maths` and `Biology`.

I now want it so:

- When you hover over it, another menu extends out on the right hand side starting in line with what's being hovered over - where I can add different pages for chosen subject

How do I implement this?

This is my current `nav.js` menu:

```js
var navigation = '<div class="container">'
navigation += '<a href="index.html"><img src="Images/homeicon.jpg" width="50" alt="Home"></a>'
navigation += '<div class="redhover">'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown">'
navigation += '<button class="dropbtn">GCSEs</button>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown-content">'
navigation += '<a href="gcsechemistry.html">Chemistry</a>'
navigation += '<a href="gcsebiology.html">Biology</a>'
navigation += '<a href="gcsemaths.html">Maths</a>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown">'
navigation += '<button class="dropbtn">A-Levels</button>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown-content">'
navigation += '<a href="alevelchemistry.html">Chemistry</a>'
navigation += '<a href="alevelbiology.html">Biology</a>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown">'
navigation += '<button class="dropbtn">University</button>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown-content">'
navigation += '<a href="telecommunications.html">Telecommunications</a>'
navigation += '<a href="electronicengineering.html">Electronic Engineering</a>'
navigation += '<a href="engineeringmathematics.html">Engineering Mathemathics</a>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown">'
navigation += '<button class="dropbtn">More</button>'
navigation += '<div class="dropdown-content">'
navigation += '<a href="aboutme.html">About me</a>'
navigation += '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5GPvJSUO4599z_ugFuoJwg">Youtube</a>'
navigation += '<a href="blog.html">Blog</a>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '</div>'
navigation += '</div>'

document.getElementById("navigation").innerHTML = navigation;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.redhover a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: why are you building (what looks like..) a static html menu in JS as opposed to just building this part through markup within the `navigation` div?

Comment: ^ Agreed. You're doing this in a needlessly difficult way. First, it's probably easier to use a unordered list and use css to get rid of the styling. Then, there's hundreds and hundreds of navigation menu tutorials, tools, examples and libraries you can google. This is very well covered area.

Comment: I've looked online, and I can't find what I want, customised answers are much easier to work with hence asking here. As for method... was advised to me here previously. (Im new to all this)... If you can show me how to do exactly the same thing in a different method that you think is easier, please do! Im all for learning more

Comment: @Rockafella do you know how to help me with my question?

Comment: @RyanBrown I appreciate you are looking for a 'customized' answer, but as the community to help, our first task is to be able to decypher what is happening with the code in the first place, hence why we ask why you have structured it the way you have. Especially for front-end examples, provide a jsfiddle/codepen example, and help us out a little so we can help you.

Comment: @Rockafella I'm not sure what you're asking for.. the link (ryanteaches.com) shows the example of how it works, and I have provided the code in my question.. I thought putting code in the question was using the jsfiddle thing?

Comment: @Rockafella https://jsfiddle.net/mfwow8r4/1/

Comment: @RyanBrown the jsfiddle doesn't appear to be rendering anything yet - is that the problem? The reason for asking for a fiddle rather than looking at the website url, is that to help effectively with the problem, we should be analysing just the code that you are looking for help with, removing any external factors from the rest of the site.

Comment: fiddles never work for me, the code on the sit is working fine though - dont worry, I figured out how to do it anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You know what, you can use `HTML` markup instead of `JS` for creating menu.

I have here a codepen work but only by clicking each item. 

https://codepen.io/beljems/pen/egopbJ

I don't have the hover event in here because, when I use both hover and click might not working well. You can also click the outside of the menu to close the drop down.

The drop down icon only show when there is drop down menu on that item.